# PHP natural sort for numbers stored as strings not working

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm getting my SQL values back like this:

```
0: {val_point: "1"}
1: {val_point: "10"}
2: {val_point: "11"}
3: {val_point: "12"}
4: {val_point: "13"}
5: {val_point: "14"}
6: {val_point: "15"}
7: {val_point: "16"}
8: {val_point: "17"}
9: {val_point: "18"}
10: {val_point: "19"}
11: {val_point: "2"}
12: {val_point: "20"}
13: {val_point: "21"}
```

I'd like them in actual numerical order (i.e., 1,2,3,4...). The values in this column are stored as strings in mySQL and I can't (for a variety of reasons) change the data type to, say, INT.

I've tried this and got the result above:

```
$sql = "select distinct `{$whereCategory}` as val_point from {$table} ORDER BY `{$whereCategory}` ASC;";
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final = natcasesort($result);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($final);
```

Comment: Just do a CAST in your query's ORDER BY statement so it interprets them as numbers not text.

Comment: @Dai Haven't used that before. Can you show me what my $sql line needs to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $sql = "select distinct `{$whereCategory}` as val_point,CONVERT({$whereCategory},UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS cat from {$table} ORDER BY cat  ASC";
```